# what causes the iteration of an array to conclude prematurely in metal?

Tags: swift, graphics, metal

## What I'm trying to do

I'm testing out metals capability to work with loops. Since I can't define new constants in metal, I'm passing a `uint` into the buffer and use it to iterate over an array filled with integers. It looks like this in swift.

```
let array1: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

## The problem(s)

However when reading the result array buffer in Swift after completing the loop in metal, it seems like not every element has been allocated.

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void shader(constant int *arr        [[ buffer(0) ]],
                   device   int *resultArray [[ buffer(1) ]],
                   constant uint &iter       [[ buffer(2) ]]) // value of 12
{
    
    for (uint i = 0; i < iter; i++){
        resultArray[i] = arr[i];
    }
    
}
```

out

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Similarly, using the iterator to set allocate each element of `resultArray`, yields strange results

```
for (uint i = 0; i < iter; i++){
        resultArray[i] = i;
    }
```

out

```
4294967296
12884901890
21474836484
30064771078
38654705672
47244640266
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Multiplication seems to work

```
for (uint i = 0; i < iter; i++){
        resultArray[i] = arr[i] * i;
    }
```

out

```
0
4
12
24
40
60
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Addition does not

```
for (uint i = 0; i < iter; i++){
        resultArray[i] = arr[i] + i;
    }
```

out

```
4294967297
12884901892
21474836487
30064771082
38654705677
47244640272
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

When however, I set `iter` to a value of for example  `24` or higher, it at least iterated over the whole arrays of size `12`.

```
for (uint i = 0; i < iter; i++){ // iter now value of 100
        resultArray[i] = arr[i] * iter;
    }
```

```
100
200
300
400
500
600
100
200
300
400
500
600
```

What is going on here?

## MCVE

yes, it's a lot of code to get a simple loop running in metal, please bare with me

main.swift

```
import MetalKit

let array1: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

func gpuProcess(arr1: [Int]) {
    
    let size = arr1.count // value of 12

    // GPU we want to use
    let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()

    // Fifo queue for sending commands to the gpu
    let commandQueue = device?.makeCommandQueue()

    // The library for getting our metal functions
    let gpuFunctionLibrary = device?.makeDefaultLibrary()

    // Grab gpu function
    let additionGPUFunction = gpuFunctionLibrary?.makeFunction(name: "shader")

    var additionComputePipelineState: MTLComputePipelineState!
    do {
        additionComputePipelineState = try device?.makeComputePipelineState(function: additionGPUFunction!)
    } catch {
      print(error)
    }

    // Create buffers to be sent to the gpu from our array
    let arr1Buff = device?.makeBuffer(bytes: arr1,
                                      length: MemoryLayout<Int>.size * size ,
                                      options: .storageModeShared)
    
    let resultBuff = device?.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout<Int>.size * size,
                                        options: .storageModeShared)

    // Create the buffer to be sent to the command queue
    let commandBuffer = commandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer()

    // Create an encoder to set values on the compute function
    let commandEncoder = commandBuffer?.makeComputeCommandEncoder()
    commandEncoder?.setComputePipelineState(additionComputePipelineState)

    // Set the parameters of our gpu function
    commandEncoder?.setBuffer(arr1Buff, offset: 0, index: 0)
    commandEncoder?.setBuffer(resultBuff, offset: 0, index: 1)
    
    // Set parameters for our iterator
    var count = size
    commandEncoder?.setBytes(&count, length: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: count), index: 2)

    // Figure out how many threads we need to use for our operation
    let threadsPerGrid = MTLSize(width: 1, height: 1, depth: 1)
    let maxThreadsPerThreadgroup = additionComputePipelineState.maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup // 1024
    let threadsPerThreadgroup = MTLSize(width: maxThreadsPerThreadgroup, height: 1, depth: 1)
    commandEncoder?.dispatchThreads(threadsPerGrid,
                                    threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)

    // Tell encoder that it is done encoding.  Now we can send this off to the gpu.
    commandEncoder?.endEncoding()

    // Push this command to the command queue for processing
    commandBuffer?.commit()

    // Wait until the gpu function completes before working with any of the data
    commandBuffer?.waitUntilCompleted()

    // Get the pointer to the beginning of our data
    var resultBufferPointer = resultBuff?.contents().bindMemory(to: Int.self,
                                                                capacity: MemoryLayout<Int>.size * size)

    // Print out all of our new added together array information
    for _ in 0..<size {
        print("\(Int(resultBufferPointer!.pointee) as Any)")
        resultBufferPointer = resultBufferPointer?.advanced(by: 1)
    }
    
}

// Call function
gpuProcess(arr1: array1)
```

**compute.metal**

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void shader(constant int *arr        [[ buffer(0) ]],
                   device   int *resultArray [[ buffer(1) ]],
                   constant uint &iter       [[ buffer(2) ]]) // value of 12
{
    
    for (uint i = 0; i < iter; i++){
        resultArray[i] = arr[i] * iter;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your swift `Int` is 64 bytes, while `int` in MSL is 32 bytes. And you compute shader doesn't make any sense, because each of the 1024 threads is doing the same thing, which can also lead to undefined results in more complex scenarios, since you are reading and writing over the same memory non-atomically over and over. As for the first problem, I recommend using types that actually specify their bit width, such as `Int32` in Swift or `int32_t`in MSL to avoid this confusion.

Comment: oof can you write an answer that I can test? I'm not sure where to apply these changes

Comment: Also, calculating array size using `MemoryLayout.size` is wrong. You should be using `stride`. It will work for integers and such, because they don't have padding and so their size is equal to stride, but any POD structure that has any padding will make your array smaller than it needs to be.

Comment: Added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 64 bit `Int` in Swift and 32 bit integers in MSL. Your GPU threads are also overlapping their work. Instead, use `Int32` in Swift and make each thread process their own piece of data. Like this

```
import MetalKit

let array1: [Int32] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

func gpuProcess(arr1: [Int32]) {
    
    let size = arr1.count // value of 12

    // GPU we want to use
    let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()

    // Fifo queue for sending commands to the gpu
    let commandQueue = device?.makeCommandQueue()

    // The library for getting our metal functions
    let gpuFunctionLibrary = device?.makeDefaultLibrary()

    // Grab gpu function
    let additionGPUFunction = gpuFunctionLibrary?.makeFunction(name: "shader")

    var additionComputePipelineState: MTLComputePipelineState!
    do {
        additionComputePipelineState = try device?.makeComputePipelineState(function: additionGPUFunction!)
    } catch {
      print(error)
    }

    // Create buffers to be sent to the gpu from our array
    let arr1Buff = device?.makeBuffer(bytes: arr1,
                                      length: MemoryLayout<Int32>.stride * size ,
                                      options: .storageModeShared)
    
    let resultBuff = device?.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout<Int32>.stride * size,
                                        options: .storageModeShared)

    // Create the buffer to be sent to the command queue
    let commandBuffer = commandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer()

    // Create an encoder to set values on the compute function
    let commandEncoder = commandBuffer?.makeComputeCommandEncoder()
    commandEncoder?.setComputePipelineState(additionComputePipelineState)

    // Set the parameters of our gpu function
    commandEncoder?.setBuffer(arr1Buff, offset: 0, index: 0)
    commandEncoder?.setBuffer(resultBuff, offset: 0, index: 1)
    
    // Set parameters for our iterator
    var count = size
    commandEncoder?.setBytes(&count, length: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: count), index: 2)

    // Figure out how many threads we need to use for our operation
    let threadsPerGrid = MTLSize(width: 1, height: 1, depth: 1)
    let maxThreadsPerThreadgroup = additionComputePipelineState.maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup // 1024
    let threadsPerThreadgroup = MTLSize(width: maxThreadsPerThreadgroup, height: 1, depth: 1)
    commandEncoder?.dispatchThreads(threadsPerGrid,
                                    threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)

    // Tell encoder that it is done encoding.  Now we can send this off to the gpu.
    commandEncoder?.endEncoding()

    // Push this command to the command queue for processing
    commandBuffer?.commit()

    // Wait until the gpu function completes before working with any of the data
    commandBuffer?.waitUntilCompleted()

    // Get the pointer to the beginning of our data
    var resultBufferPointer = resultBuff?.contents().bindMemory(to: Int32.self,
                                                                capacity: MemoryLayout<Int32>.stride * size)

    // Print out all of our new added together array information
    for _ in 0..<size {
        print("\(Int32(resultBufferPointer!.pointee) as Any)")
        resultBufferPointer = resultBufferPointer?.advanced(by: 1)
    }
    
}

// Call function
gpuProcess(arr1: array1)
```

Kernel:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void shader(constant int *arr        [[ buffer(0) ]],
                   device   int *resultArray [[ buffer(1) ]],
                   constant uint &iter       [[ buffer(2) ]],
                   uint gid [[ thread_position_in_grid ]], // this is thread index in grid, since you have height and depth of a dispatch set to 1 in CPU code, you can use 1D `int` here.
)
{
    // Early out if gid is out of array boudns
    if(gid >= iter)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Each thread processes it's own data
    resultArray[gid] = arr[gid] * iter;
}
```

For more information on how to use Metal for compute refer to [developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/performing_calculations_on_a_gpu) and for the information about attributes such as `thread_position_in_grid` refer to [Metal Shading Language specification.](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf)

Comment: My specific goal for this was to get for loops running in metal to eventually run Dijkstra in a shader. This get's rid of the for loop, which is kind of past the point

Comment: using `int` for `gid`: `ERROR: Type 'int' is not valid for attribute 'thread_position_in_grid'`

running this with `uint`  returns `12
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0`

Comment: Updated the answer, forgot to update your debug code. You should be able to get the gist from the answer and use available tools such as GPU Debugger and regular CPU debugger to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Replacing `resultArray[gid] = arr[gid] * iter;` from with the for loop from my example it performs the addition. Now I can make multiple threads work on different parts of a matrix for example or parallelize other matrix operations. Being able to run arithmetically correct operations using loops is a giant breakthrough -
thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind that nothing prevents you from running whichever code you want in the threads. You can loop over some data in the same thread or use other threads, that's the beauty of this simd model.

Comment: Could you suggest a better title for this question? I feel like it’s not capturing the issue very well, considering all the problems are encoding related